# Как сделать автоматический вывод description в head?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

Как на `php` сделать автоматический вывод `description` в `head`? Описание должно извлекаться из самой статьи. Работаю с `WordPress`.

Спасибо!

**UPD:** Я делаю вот так:

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

В google работает, а вот в яндексе нет. А мне нужно так, чтобы ещё и исходном коде страницы выводилось описание. Например:

```
<meta name="description" content="В этой статье мы расскажет и т.п." />
```

Comment: @MicKe, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте плагин `all-in-one-seo-pack` и для каждой страницы указывайте нужный Вам дескрипшен.

Comment: такой вариант гораздо лучвше, потому что будете получать в дескрипшене точный текст, а не вырванный из контекста статьи.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы.